# Which program in Visual Studio lets me look into DLLs to see its API?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008

See the question. I want to see the methods and classes offered by a DLLs library.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This is exactly what the Object Browser is for.

- Add a reference to the DLL.
- Right click it in the list.
- Click *View in Object Browser*.

Comment: You can also use File->Open->File and browse to the DLL file if you do not want to add it as a reference.

Comment: If File->Open->File doesn't open the file in the Object Browser, use the drop-down menu on the "open" button, and choose "Open with..." and select "object browser" from the list.  You can also make it the default at that point.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: I tried but it does not even allow to add a reference to dll. Or I cannot add a reference to dll in an existing project, so I must open a new project?

Comment: I tried to use the File->Open->File suggestion above, but could only see version information, which wasn't useful. When I actually added the DLL as a reference, so much more data was available to browse.

Answer (score 17):

For those coming from the old Visual Studio 6.0 days:

**Dependency Walker** is a nice free tool, that was formerly part of Visual Studio.

http://www.dependencywalker.com/

I like it still. Here is a screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Does this work on .NET DLLs or just native assembly DLLs?  The documentation seems to say the latter.  OP tagged .NET in his question as if he asking about .NET.

Answer (score 8):

- [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) is an open-source tool which allows you to browse an assembly's packages and classes and also to decompile code.
- Another free-of-charge tool is [JetBrain's dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/).

Answer (score 6):

There's also the [DLL export viewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html) if you don't have VS installed on a machine.

Answer (score 6):

If the DLL is a .NET assembly you might want to take a look at [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/index.htm) for a more detailed view.

Answer (score 6):

If you have limited options to download: In Visual Studio you could use Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt.
Open it from windows menu -> All programs -> Visual Studio XX -> Visual Studio Tools -> Developer Command Prompt.
Then: run command: `ildasm`

Example [ildasm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ildasm-exe-il-disassembler):

```
ildasm c:\MyNetAssembly.dll
```

If you have access to download any program you could use better options:
[IlSpy](http://ilspy.net/)
[dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)
[.net reflector](https://www.red-gate.com/dynamic/products/dotnet-development/reflector/download)
[JustDecompile](https://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

There's a dependency tracker tool that comes with the Windows SDK (formerly the Platform SDK), it's got a reasonable GUI for looking inside executables and DLL's.

There are also some command line tools that you can use to see inside of dll's, dumpbin in particular - check the MSDN help in visual studio for more information. You can run these tools from the command prompt in the Visual Studio start menu folder.

Answer (score 1):

Outside of Visual Studio, you can use a dependency tool which is able to inspect DLL and EXE imports and exports, it integrates with the shell and is very easy to use. It comes  with some Microsoft SDKs. If you want to avoid the hassle of downloading and installing SDK just because of this, easy download links for all 32b/64b platforms are available at http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Microsoft documentation (no download) is available at [MicroSoft Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738370.aspx)

Similar functionality is also available in SysInternals Process Explorer - best suited when inspecting running processes.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2022 (and without creating or opening a solution) you can view a DLL's members.

1. Open the Object Browser Tool Window (from the View option in the Main Menu).
2. In that window it'll probably show a list of .NET components, but near the top there's a browse button (three dots). Click this.
3. Here you'll add any DLLs you want to create a "Custom Component Set". Once you select and Add your DLL, then click OK.

You should see your DLL members in the Object Browser now.