# I need to obtain a list of public methods exposed by "ieframe.dll"

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer

I know two of them are IERegCreateKeyEx() and IERegSetValueEx().  But I don't know what else is available on the library.

I'd like to use something equivalent to an "IERegOpenKeyEx()" but don't know if or how it exists or how it's parameter are defined.  Thank you for any help.

Comment: Do you mean [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh802023(v=vs.85))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use decompilation tools like Telerik's JustDecompile to access the dll's public methods.

You can download this tool from [here](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

What you want to look for is a C# reflector or decompiler.

Since C# uses reflection, it is very easy to go into a .dll and look for methods. In face, Visual Studio does this on its own.

Either way, to get a nice tree of classes and methods, I am sure there is a way to do this in VS, but a straightforward way would be to just use one of these tools to explore the .dll.

**EDIT: This has already been answered before** -
[Which program in Visual Studio lets me look into DLLs to see its API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131985/which-program-in-visual-studio-lets-me-look-into-dlls-to-see-its-api)