# Expose Class from Assembly

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection, .net-assembly

I tried to found the solution, but i fail...

from an gived assembly i have get to get all "class names" containing it.
this seems simple, but the problem is when the target assembly theres some references NOT resolved. For example, this code works well when the target assemblies do not depends from any other:

```
Dim loAssembly As Reflection.Assembly = Reflection.Assembly.Load(loRawAssembly)
Dim loTypes As Type() = loAssembly.GetTypes()

For Each t As Type In loTypes
    If t.IsClass Then

      'do something with class names

    End If
Next t
```

If i use AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve, to resolve the assembly needed then works, but not ever will be possible to determine IT. 
Then I'd like to know if theres another way to get the class name from an give assembly ?

Tks.

Comment: If you just want the meta-information for the assembly items, have you tried `ReflectionOnlyLoad`? Outside of that, it wouldn't make sense for you to be able load an assembly that has unresolved dependencies (for use). How would you use a method, say, that made a call to a class that doesn't exist?

Comment: I had already tried this but ReflectionOnlyLoad also does't works.I agree that don't make sense if i would try to call some method in the same moment i Load the assembly, but the intention is: 
* load the assembly and with GetTypes() get all class that Implements an specific Interface, then i preserve the className that match this.
* by another app, that works like an AbstractFactory,  have all references loaded, and will consume the info above, using assembly + className to create an instance and call the method i need

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.reflectiononlyloadfrom%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  I don't believe it requires referenced assemblies to be loaded.

From MSDN Doc:

> Dependencies are not automatically loaded into the reflection-only
>   context.

Comment: also does't works, the moment that GetTypes() is called its try to load all assembly references. Tks

Answer (score 0):

tks for help.

I found my solution here, using the Mono.Cecil:

[Finding classes in a DLL that inherit from classes in an unavailable assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050888/finding-classes-in-a-dll-that-inherit-from-classes-in-an-unavailable-assembly?rq=1)

Now my code works doing this:

```
Imports Mono.Cecil
Imports Mono.Cecil.Cil

Dim loMemStream As New IO.MemoryStream(pRawBytes)
Dim loListOfClass As New List(Of String)
Dim loAssDefininition As AssemblyDefinition = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(loMemStream)
Dim loTypes = loAssDefininition.MainModule.Types

 For Each elemento In loTypes
     If elemento.HasInterfaces Then
         For Each loInterface In elemento.Interfaces
            If UCase(loInterface.FullName) = UCase(pTargetInterface) Then
                 loListOfClass.Add(elemento.FullName)
            End If
         Next
    End If
 Next
 Return loListOfClass
```