# VS2015 linker error with python extension

Tags: python, c, zlib

I'm trying to build my own python (3.5.2) c extension that depends on zlib. With gcc on linux it works perfectly but I can't seem to make it work on windows 64-bit.

I installed zlib dll according to the instructions:

```
Installing ZLIB1.DLL
====================
  Copy ZLIB1.DLL to the SYSTEM or the SYSTEM32 directory.


Using ZLIB1.DLL with Microsoft Visual C++
=========================================
   1. Install the supplied header files "zlib.h" and "zconf.h"
      into a directory found in the INCLUDE path list.

   2. Install the supplied library file "zdll.lib" into a
      directory found in the LIB path list.

   3. Add "zdll.lib" to your project.
```

My setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize([Extension("esp", ["bethlib/esp.pyx", "bethlib/c_esp.c", "bethlib/linked_list.c"], libraries=["zdll"], include_dirs=["include"], library_dirs=["lib"])]),
)
```

Trying to build with `python setup.py bdist_wheel` gives the error:

```
c_esp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol uncompress
build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\esp.cp35-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
error: command 'E:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120
```

`uncompress` is a valid function present in zlib.h. Any solutions? Thanks!

Comment: On Windows you have to build your extension with the same version of VS that was used to build the Python interpreter and presumably `zlib.dll` (or alternatively use gcc).

Comment: Yes, VS2015 (the visual c++ compiler 14.0) was used and zlib recommends zlib1.dll which I installed as per the intructions

Comment: Did you make sure zlib is the x64 version?

Comment: zlib only offers 1 dll, how can I find that out? The architecture is never referred to in any of the FAQs :/

Comment: You might be able to check what's actually in the dll. See [_Which program in Visual Studio lets me look into DLLs to see its API?_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131985/which-program-in-visual-studio-lets-me-look-into-dlls-to-see-its-api)

Comment: If you need a 64-bit Windows version of `zlib`, it sounds like you're going to need to build it (it looks like they [only supply a prebuilt win32](http://zlib.net/zlib_faq.html#faq02) version).

Comment: [That seems to be the issue.](http://i.imgur.com/uoFVEDD.png) I rarely use windows so if you could add an answer with at least a link to a working tutorial to compile zlib in windows 64-bit I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Looking at the `README.txt` file for `zlib` version 1.2.8, it looks like it was built using the `mingw32-gcc` version of `gcc`, so you should be able to build a 64-bit version of it to get what you need. Does your extension _really_ need to be 64-bit?

Comment: If the python is 64-bit then yes, download source for zlib, build it for 64bit (I think it was cmake. I had to do that a few months ago.)

Comment: I tried building a 32-bit extension (with 32-bit python) but it didn't load in windows

Comment: go to command shell, type "python", and you should enter the interpreter. It will print a version string, which includes whether it is 32 bit or 64 bit. If you successfully built a 32-bit python extension, but it didn't work in python (failed on the import command) then there is a different reason, having to do with juggling both the python path and the dll load path (this is also the case in posix). You could post that error message.

Comment: The error was `ImportError: DLL load failed` but I do need a 64bit version too. In ubuntu I had no errors at all though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the static zlib lib from [this website](http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/index.html) and it works. It's for an older version so I'd still appreciate if I could get a more current version but for now it's enough.