# How can I find out which events prints on Output window in VS2019?

Tags: xamarin.forms, honeywell

I'm working on a scanner app with honeywell nuget package.
In VS2019 output window I can see this message every time a barcode gets scanned:

```
[BarcodeReader] Received barcode data:EDA50-HB-R CodeId:j AimId:]C0
```

Is there a way to know which event prints it and add a listener to it?

Comment: this is most likely generated inside the library and may not be tied to any public event

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which program in Visual Studio lets me look into DLLs to see its API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131985/which-program-in-visual-studio-lets-me-look-into-dlls-to-see-its-api) - or simply rt-click on any reference (in your code) to a class that is in the nuget, "Go to definition" - will show "ThatClassName (from metadata)". Not directly what you ask, but this shows what is publicly available.